# Mod_rewrite with multiple variables

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, png, css, rgba

I'm using a PHP script that dynamically generates transparent PNGs for use as CSS backgrounds from a query string that takes RGBa and HSLa values. The original script can be found [here](http://leaverou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/), I've only added HSLa support.

Because background URLs with PHP query strings aren't very pretty, and because it seems to break the IE 6 transparent PNG hack, I thought of using mod_rewrite to allow the script to be called when a .png with this syntax is called :

```
/assets/colors/h[0-360 value]_s[0-100 value]_l[0-100 value]_a[0-100 value].png
```

which would be rewritten to :

```
/assets/colors.php?h=[0-360 value]&s=[0-100 value]&l=[0-100 value]&a=[0-100 value]
```

Here's the issues I'm encountering :

- passing multiple variables with mod_rewrite
- using an underscore as a delimiter

I know this could be done by passing a single variable and then exploding it in the PHP script, however I would prefer it to be done by Apache.

Thanks in advance and if anyone wants my HSLa enabled version of the script just ask. Anyway I recommend you check it out on it's author's website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite will match things in braces (), and then you can refer to these as $1, $2, etc in the order they were matched. So you can use this to extract multiple variables by just placing them inside braces.

So something like this will work for you,

```
RewriteRule ^assets/colors/h([0-9]{1,3})_s([0-9]{1,3})_l([0-9]{1,3})_a([0-9]{1,3}).png assets/colors.php?h=$1&s=$2&l=$3&a=$4
```

`([0-9]{1,3})` will match either 1, 2 or 3 of the numbers 0-9 in a row. So "3", "10" and "100", etc. But it would also match "999", so you'll need to make sure the colors.php file checks the values are within expected ranges, etc.

Comment: Thanks ! Works like a charm. I understand the need to check that the variables be in the correct range but since I'm not exposing the script to user input I can do without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /assets/colors/h([0-9]+)_s([0-9]+)_l([0-9]+)_a([0-9]+).png /assets/col.php?h=$1&s=$2&l=$3&a=$4 [QSA,L]
```

I had to changeup my script name to make this work. Because I have `Options MultiViews`, /assets/colors/ is always handled by colors.php regardless of the mod_rewrite configuration.

Comment: Thanks ! Why are you suggesting using the [QSA] flag ?

Comment: QSA is "query string append," so if you decide to build in additional query string parameters like `h100_s100_l100_a100.png?v=1`, the `v=1` portion will be appended to the rest of the query string built in the destination URL. I usually add it out of habit.